# Extract text between two tags and save each result in separate files

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I want to retrieve whatever is between these two tags `<data ... - </ data>` and export each result in a separate text file
This command works very well, but unfortunately output is one file :-(

```
sed -n '/<data*/,/<\/data>/p' Input.txt > Output.txt
```

Do you have any suggestion for this?

Thanks

Comment: Please supply a sample input file.

Comment: Please provide example

Answer (score 1):

You can get the results into separate containers if we forward the **sed** o/p to
**csplit**

```
sed -e '/<report>/,\|</report>|!d' input.txt |
csplit -s -z -f Output -  '/<\/report>/+1' '{*}'
```

- Depending on the file input, you will see Output00, Output01,...
- The splitting is done on the line following the regex